# Best way to calculate multiple cells by id value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming i have user table to my clients can register itemid and prices. My database structure like:

```
userid  createddate itemid  itemprice
1       2021-18-01  gtsk    141
1       2021-17-01  hvb1    136
1       2021-17-01  gtsk    134
1       2021-15-01  hvb1    128
1       2021-10-01  hvb1    122
2       2021-18-01  gtsk    141
2       2021-17-01  hvb1    136
2       2021-17-01  gtsk    134
```

I'm planning to make a simple pie chart graph with using above data. But in this case theres a duplicated label tagged by user.(userid_1 has a already 2x gtsk labaled data). That because my chart graph seems broken because of duplicate label thing. I want to sum sam labaled data before the deploy data.

Thats the point the that im confused, because i can't way out the print results as unique itemid. My first plan was a create a new columnn and sum 'itemprice' which is having same itemid and userid. But where it should be written? another table? shall i create new column right to itemprice?

In quite scenario expect result must be like:

```
userid  createddate itemid  itemprice   totalprice
1         2021-18-01    gtsk    141     275   
1         2021-17-01    hvb1    136     386
1         2021-17-01    gtsk    134 
1         2021-15-01    hvb1    128 
1         2021-15-01    hvb1    122 
2         2021-18-01    gtsk    141    341
2         2021-17-01    hvb1    136    136
2         2021-17-01    gtsk    200
```

275 = userid1.gtsk (2021-17-01) + userid1.gtsk ( 2021-18-01 )

I can call and sum values as below code:

```
select itemid, user_id, sum(itemprice)
from usertable
group by itemid, user_id
```

My Problem is:

1- If i use that query with UPDATE operator it will be update every cell in that row. I just need to update only one with new calculated value.

2- Is there any other\simple\clean way to calculate itemprices ?

I searched on google and on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything that could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `row_number` and `sum` analytical function as follows:

```
select userid, createddate, itemid, itemprice,
       case when row_number() over (partition by userid, itemid order by createddate) = 1 
            then sum(itemprice) over (partition by userid, itemid) 
       end as totalprice
  from usertable;
```

Comment: Its quite brililiant code. What would you recommend to store all those output?

Comment: `Create table .. as select..` or according to your requirement `insert into .. select ..`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily calculate the total price using a window function. No need to store it anywhere.

```
select userid, createddate, itemid, itemprice,
       sum(itemprice) over (partition by createddate, userid, itemid) as totalprice
from the_table;
```